# Having trouble using update and upgrade for Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, kubuntu

I am running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and getting the below error:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                             
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022 focal InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                                
Ign:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy jammy InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                   
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:10 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                 
Err:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy jammy Release                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.90.21.104 443]
Hit:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:16 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                     
Hit:15 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                         
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

Results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
# Microsoft repository for Ubuntu jammy
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod/ jammy main
 
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS w_Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230223)]/ jammy main multiverse restricted universe
 
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
 
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
 
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
 
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
 
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
 
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
 
# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

trying `sudo sed -i -e 's|impish|jammy|g' /etc/apt/sources.list` and this did not seem to do anything. Another post suggested changing the server on Software & Updates. I changed from my local server to the Main server and was able to fetch the files.

I'm not sure where to find my Software & Updates app to try this suggestion out. I'm also looking to update to 23.04 so I'm unsure if this needs to be done before I do so.

Also https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy brings me to a `404 Not found` screen.

Comment: The path you want should be at https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod/

Comment: @rockyrocky I went into /etc/apt/sources.list and added # Microsoft repository for Ubuntu jammy
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod jammy main
but still getting same error - do i need to remove a line? file here : https://pastebin.com/axN0GF5i

Comment: Follow the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linux/packages.
If the deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-jammy-prod/ jammy main exists in /etc/apt/sources.list, please comment it.
I am sorry for the confusion caused by the previous reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable Microsoft Products in Ubuntu:

1. Download the repo config package:

```
curl -sSL -O https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

2. Install the repo config package: `sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb`
3. Delete the repo config package after installing: `rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb`
4. To install the Microsoft product package you're after using this Linux repository (packages.microsoft.com): `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`